# Wrong figure reference number

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I'm trying to insert a figure in a LaTeX file, but LaTeX always gives the reference number of this figure as figure 1 instead of 2, although there is already a figure 1 earlier in the document. I also can't reference this figure using `~\ref{fig:regress}`. The figure number just doesn't print.

Here's the code I used to insert the image in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}  

I'm trying to reference Figure~\ref{fig:regress} here...

\begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{im1.png}
                \caption{Scatter plot fitted with straight line}
                \label{fig:linfit}
        \end{subfigure}%

        \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{im2.png}
                \caption{Scatter plot fitted with 2nd degree polynomial}
                \label{fig:quadfit}
        \end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{im3.png}
                \caption{Scatter plot fitted with 3rd degree polynomial} 
                \label{fig:cubicfit}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption{Scatter plots of wavelength vs. pixel position for the spectrum from night 1, fitted with polynomials of orders 1-3.}   \label{fig:regress}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I checked that I have `\label` and `\caption` in the right order. What's going on?

Comment: Recently, there was a question about the very same concern. Can you look at the solution and see if it helps you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85827/11002

Comment: Have you at least checked the log? It says ``! Package caption Error: Continued `figure' after `??'. `` There’s no problem when adding a separate caption to the first `figure` environment or removing `\ContinuedFloat` from the second. In every instance, the second figure’s subfigure enumeration is still `(c)`.

Comment: I don't get that error when I run it. What confounds me even more is when I move the line `\caption{Scatter plots of wavelength vs. pixel position for the spectrum from night 1, fitted with polynomials of orders 1-3.}   \label{fig:regress}` to just above the first subfigure, it works (except the caption is now on top of the figures).

Comment: @myrthen You don’t get that because you have another figure/caption before that in your original code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When compiling your MWE with `pdflatex` I get the error

```
! Package caption Error: Continued `figure' after `??'.
```

Whatever that means … *(I have used neither `caption` nor `subcaption` before.)*

Apparently `caption` is confused when you use `\ContinuedFloat` in a `figure` environment when the preceding one doesn’t had a `\caption`; which isn’t very surprising because there isn’t much to continue. To fix this, **add a `\phantomcaption` to the first `figure` environment**. <sup>[See [Axel Sommerfeldt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2574/axel-sommerfeldt)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86166/wrong-figure-reference-number/86180#comment185744_86180).]</sup>

If you do want to include a caption in the first `figure` environment, of course, you must not use `\phantomcaption`.

### Code

Note that I have removed every reference to an external graphic because

- I don’t have them.
- I don’t need them.

I also removed `\usepackage{caption}`, it does get already loaded by `subcaption`.
The `chngcntr` package does not interfere with this MWE.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{fig:before}\label{fig:before}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:before}.

I'm trying to reference Figure~\ref{fig:regress}, subfigure~\ref{fig:linfit} and \ref{fig:quadfit} as well as \ref{fig:cubicfit} here.

\hrulefill
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \caption{Scatter plot fitted with straight line}
    \label{fig:linfit}
  \end{subfigure}%

  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \caption{Scatter plot fitted with 2nd degree polynomial}
    \label{fig:quadfit}
  \end{subfigure}
  \phantomcaption%                                                                                                                  either a phantom caption
%  \caption{Scatteru plots of wavelength vs. pixel position for the spectrum from night 1, fitted with polynomials of orders 1-3.}% or a real one
\end{figure}

\hrulefill
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
    \caption{Scatter plot fitted with 3rd degree polynomial} 
    \label{fig:cubicfit}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Scatteru plots of wavelength vs. pixel position for the spectrum from night 1, fitted with polynomials of orders 1-3.}   \label{fig:regress}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately "you don’t need \ContinuedFloat" is wrong. There are some internals of the `caption`, `subfig` and `subcaption` package which actually will need this information, so other things can go wrong when you omit it. So better use `\phantomcaption` (without arguments) in the 1st figure and `\ContinuedFloat` in the 2nd one. (The need of `\phantomcaption` will be fixed in caption v3.3)

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks for the insight. As I wrote, I am no expert in (`sub`)`caption` and don’t know the internals. I’ve updates my answer, though. When will v3.3 come out? “The need of `\phantomcaption` will be fixed”? Does this mean that `\ContinuedFloat` works as OP expected or that it can be removed safely as in the previous revision of my answer?

Comment: This means that `\ContinuedFloat` will work as the OP expected. Version v3.3 will hopefully be released within the next weeks, at least I'm just working again on it after a long pause.

Answer (score 16):

**Adding an additional cause for this type of behavior**

I had a similar issue with a document I am working on that had the following structure:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet shown in Figure~\ref{foo-bar-diagram}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{assets/foo_bar_diagram.pdf}\label{foo-bar-diagram}
\caption{Foo bar bin baz}
\end{figure}
```

This resulted in the following output:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet shown in Figure 4.
>
> <graphic> 
> Figure 1: Foo bar bin baz

The reason for this is because the `label` is in the wrong location. Putting it after the `caption` fixed the output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet shown in Figure~\ref{foo-bar-diagram}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{assets/foo_bar_diagram.pdf}
\caption{Foo bar bin baz}
\label{foo-bar-diagram}
\end{figure}
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet shown in Figure 1.
>
> <graphic> 
> Figure 1: Foo bar bin baz

Comment: This was my problem. Great post

Comment: Thank you for your post.

Comment: you are a genuine hero for this one

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had my label right after my `\begin{figure}`, which was causing me grief.